# Фильтр цен от минимального до максимального. laravel

Tags: php, laravel, blade

Всем доброго дня! Не получается сделать фильтр от минимального до максимального значения. У меня есть контроллер в котором я сравниваю цену с введенными значениями в инпуты на view:

**Контроллер**

```
$postValues = Post::where(function($query)
{
    if (request()->has('min_value')) {
        request()->get('min_value');
    } else {
        $min_value = null;
    }
    if (request()->has('max_value')) {
        request()->get('max_value');
    } else {
        $max_price = null;
    }

    if(isset($min_value) && isset($max_value))
    {
        $query->where('price','>=',$min_value);
        $query->where('price','<=',$max_value);
    }

})->get()->toArray();

view()->share('postValues', $postValues);
```

**View**

```
<div class="block-title has-arrow sidebar-header">
  <form role="form" class="form-inline" action="{{ $fullUrlNoParams }}" method="GET">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-4 no-padding">
      <input type="text" placeholder="min year" id="min_value" name="min_value" class="form-control"
            value="{{request()->get('min_value')}}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-4 no-padding">
      <input type="text" placeholder="max year" id="max_value" name="max_value" class="form-control"
            value="{{request()->get('max_value')}}">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-default pull-right btn-block-xs" type="submit">{{ t('GO') }}</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Ничего не работает. Я новенький и уверен, что-то не так сделал или вообще не так делаю. Подскажите в чем проблема.

Comment: можно попробовать `whereBeetwen` для запроса от и до.  Типа `Post::whereBeetwen('price', [$min, $max])`

Comment: а что именно не работает? игнорирует фильтр? Вы обязательно вводите мин и макс?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы проверяете наличие цены, но забыли ее потом присвоить в переменные:

```
$min_value = request()->get('min_value');
$max_value = request()->get('max_value');
```

Код целиком:

```
$postValues = Post::where(function($query)
    {
        if (request()->has('min_value')) {
            $min_value = request()->get('min_value');
        } else {
            $min_value = null;
        }
        if (request()->has('max_value')) {
            $max_value = request()->get('max_value');
        } else {
            $max_price = null;
        }

        if(isset($min_value) && isset($max_value))
        {
            $query->where('price','>=',$min_value);
            $query->where('price','<=',$max_value);
        }

    })->get()->toArray();
```

А в целом, как вам уже подсказали в комментах, лучше через whereBetween

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте

```
    $postValues = Post::query();
      $min_value = null;
      $max_price = null;  
    if (request()->get('min_value')) {
       $min_value = request()->get('min_value');
    }
    if (request()->get('max_value')) {
       $max_price = request()->get('max_value');
    }

    if($min_value && $max_price) {
        $postValues = $postValues->whereBetween('price', [$min_value, $max_price])
    }

    $postValues = $postValues->get()->toArray();

    view()->share('postValues', $postValues);
```